# Run for loop to show posts, but make 3rd card always show post with specific tag

Tags: html, for-loop, twig, hubspot, hubl

This question is regarding `HubSpot`/`HuBl`, but I am also tagging `twig` as the syntaxes are similar.

I have a blog layout containing 7 cards and has the following structure:

[image]

For reference, the class modifiers for the above are:

1. `blogCard`
2. `blogCard`
3. `blogCard--long`
4. `blogCard`
5. `blogCard`
6. `blogCard--wide`
7. `blogCard`

Now, in `HubL`, I'm trying to loop though posts and where the `loop.index` is equal to `three`, I want it to show a blog post which has the tag of `video`. This `video` post will appear in `blogCard--long`.

So all other 6 cards can show posts with any tag, but the 3rd (`blogCard--long`) must be a post with the tag of `video`.

To achieve this, I have tried the following:

```html
<!-- get all posts from blog -->
{% set all_posts = blog_recent_posts(blog_id, 21) %}

<!-- find all posts with the tag "video" -->
{% set video_posts = blog_recent_tag_posts(blog_id, 'video') %}

<!-- remove video posts from all_posts array -->
{% set posts =  all_posts|difference(video_posts) %}

{% for post in posts %}

  <div class="blogCard"></div>

  {% if (loop.index == 3) %}
    {% for video_post in video_posts %}
      <div class="blogCard--long">{{ video_post.name }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}

  <div class="blogCard"></div>

  {% if loop.index == 6 %}
   <div class="latestBlogs__blog--wide"></div>
  {% endif %}
 
  <div class="blogCard"></div>

{% endfor %}
```

I am essentially running the initial `posts` loop on all posts excluding those tagged with `video`. Then, when encountering the third item, I'm running a nested loop to obtain data from a video post. However, since it is a nested loop, it shows ***all*** of the video posts in one loop iterations. For example, if I have two posts that are tagged with `video`, on one iteration, it will show both those video posts.

Just looking to advice on the logic I'm applying here and what the best way would be to achieve this?

Comment: As seen in the [documentation](https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/cms/hubl/functions#blog-recent-tag-posts), you can specify a 3rd argument for `blog_recent_tag_posts`, which controls how many posts are returned

Comment: @DarkBee - How many posts are returned in `video_posts` is not really the issue, unless I'm missing something? I looking for a way to make the 3rd card pull from `video_posts` and then, when the main loop runs again, show the next video post (so no cards are showing the same content)

Comment: Thought the issue you were having was that 2 video posts were shown?

Comment: @DarkBee - Yes that is happening. But, if I set a limit on `blog_recent_tag_posts` i.e. to `1`. When the loop runs again, it will show the same video post again

Comment: Okay so basically you want to repeat the grid you have, because you can have more than 6 posts?

Comment: @DarkBee - So, one `slide` refers to 7 grid items (like in the image above). The number of `slides` rendered will depend on how many blog posts exist that have the tag `video`. So, if there are `three` blogs with the tag `video`, there will be `three slides`. In each single `slide`, the third card (`blogCard--long`) will always be a post that has the tag `video`. All other grid items are posts that don't have the tag `video`, but `blogCard--long` will always be a post tagged with `video`. Hopefully that makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

After reading through the comments, you could use batch to repeat the grid.
I would do something like the following:

```
{% for row in blogs|batch(6, '&nbsp;') %}
<div class="wrapper">
    {% for blog in row %}
        {% if loop.index == 3 %}
        <div class="long">
            {{ videos[loop.parent.loop.index0]|default }}
        </div>
        {% endif %}
        <div{% if loop.index == 5 %} class="wide"{% endif %}>
            {{ blog }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/bhdzsf)

The first line, `{% for row in blogs|batch(6, '&nbsp;') %}` will turn your collection in an array of 6 items each, which you then can loop to create one full grid.

If the index equals 3 you then can "prepend" one video post.
Here I use the loop variable from the first loop:

```html
loop.parent.loop.index0
```

This index you then can use to fetch a video on that index, chained with the default filter if the videos is non-existent

---

```css
    .wrapper {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-rows: 200px 200px 200px;
        grid-template-columns: 200px 200px 200px;
        grid-gap: 10px;
        margin: 0 0 20px;
    }

    .wrapper div {
        border-radius: 10px;
        background: #333333;
        color: #FFFFFF;
    }

    .wrapper .long {
        grid-row: span 2;
        grid-column: 3;
    }

    .wrapper .wide {
        grid-column: span 2;
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div class="long">vid1</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div class="wide">5</div>
    <div>6</div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
    <div class="long">vid2</div>
    <div>9</div>
    <div>10</div>
    <div class="wide">11</div>
    <div>12</div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div>13</div>
    <div>14</div>
    <div class="long">vid3</div>
    <div>15</div>
    <div>16</div>
    <div class="wide">17</div>
    <div>18</div>
</div>
```